# Errors when drawing large Graphs in Networkx

Tags: python, graph, data-visualization, networkx

I am trying to visualize a bipartite graph that has about 300,000 nodes total. I'm using my helper function below.

```
def plot_network(G):
   pos = nx.spring_layout(G) 
   plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)) 
   nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, iterations=20, node_grouping='bipartite', 
   with_labels=False, node_size = 5)

plot_network(G)
```

When I try to visualize the Graph in its entirety, the following errors pops up in the IPython cell and the process just hangs there forever:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\networkx\drawing\layout.py:499: RuntimeWarning:

invalid value encountered in sqrt
```

I tried visualizing smaller graphs by taking random samples of my data and it has worked...until the samples go above 9000 nodes.

I am not sure how to interpret the error I'm getting, but it seems graph size is a factor. So, is there a limitation on the size of graphs I can visualize in Networkx? Is there anyway I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Networkx just couldn't allocate enough space for all the nodes, try increase the `figsize` or shrink `node_size` first. If neither of those works, try upgrade the networkx package with `pip install networkx --upgrade` since it seems like you're not using the latest version of networkx.

Comment: Changing nodesize didn't work. Why do you think I'm using an old version of networkx? I'm using networkx 2.1 at the moment and it is the latest stable version.

Comment: I've just encountered this problem in 2.1 too. I have tried increasing plot size and decreasing node size to no avail, i suppose there is some combination that works but its not a "hard fix".

Comment: also, I have heard networkX is not very much suitable with high dimensionality data. GraphFrames seems an alternative but does not have whole lot of methods

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Bubble Bubble's answer suggestions, try using a simpler layout algorithm. Originally I was hitting this error using spring_layout, but I found circular works.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(25,25))

# Define node positions using layout algo
# pos = nx.spring_layout(G, center=(1,1), k=40, iterations=5) # returns error
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

# draw
nx.draw(G,axis=axs, pos=pos, node_size=1)
```